# iOS cordova project - Group plugin files in folder under Plugins/

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, xcode-project

I'm writing a `cordova ios plugin`, I managed to set the `plugin.xml` file correctly in order to work and import my plugin inside the project with

```
cordova plugin add myplugin --searchpath=path/to/my/plugin --save
```

command. What I'd like to do now is to group all the plugin files inside a folder.

For example, having these 2 files (snippet from `plugin.xml`)

```
...
<source-file src="src/ios/MyPlugin.m" />
<source-file src="src/ios/MyPlugin.h" />
...
```

I'd like to group them under MyPlugin folder, inside the iOS project Plugins folder:

```
MY_PROJECT
 |-- www/
 |-- Staging/
 |-- Classes/
 |-- Plugins/
 | |-- MyPlugin/ <!-- HERE -->
 | | |-- MyPlugin.m
 | | |-- MyPlugin.h
 | |-- SomeOtherPlugin.m
 | |-- Foo.h
 |-- Other Sources/
 |-- Resources/
 |-- Framework/
 |-- Products/
```

Right now, cordova's CLI plugin manager seems to throw any plugin file inside the Plugins folder, despite the plugin they belong to.

Is there anything equivalent to Android's `target-dir` attribute for iOS? Any hint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First , based on the [official document](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#resource-file) : ios also support `<source-file src="src/ios/MyPlugin.m" target-dir="xxxxx"/>` , however cordova just copy the file to "xxxxx" folder in the file system , which could not be reflected to Xcode project structure.

Actually what you want is to specify "Group" for ios source file , while
unfortunately , currently it seems cordova doesn't support it

Comment: That's a shame for Cordova!